# Querying many to many graphql and sqlite

Tags: graphql

I'm trying to create an Angular7 + graphql + sqlite game app and i'm stuck.

I've 3 db tables, one for games, other for genres and a third one as a relational table between games and genres.

What I want to do on graphql is basically this join:

```
SELECT G.*, GN.genre FROM Games AS G
LEFT JOIN Game_Genre AS GG ON G.id  = GG.game_id 
LEFT JOIN Genre AS GN ON GG.genre_id  = GN.id 
WHERE G.id={GAMEID}
```

[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1T3v8.png)

I managed to create queries to list all games and individual games, but I can't make any queries to list the games with their genres.

Here's the schema I'm using:

```
const schema = buildSchema(`
    type Query {
    games(offset:Int = 0, limit:Int = 100): [Games]
    game(id:ID!): Games
}

type Games {
    id: ID
    game_art: String
    game_title: String
    game_serial: String
    game_region: String
    release_year: Int
    players: Int
    developer: String
    publisher: String
}

type Genre {
  id: ID
  genre: String
}

type Game_Genre {
  id: Int
  game_id: Games
  genre_id: Genre
}`);

const root = {
games: args => {
    return query(
        `SELECT * FROM Games LIMIT ${args.offset}, ${args.limit}`,
        false
    );
},
game: args => {
    return query(`SELECT * FROM Games WHERE id='${args.id}'`, true);
}};
```

Thank you in advance